# Adding to a counter on each frame for a quiz in python tkinter?

Tags: python, function, class, tkinter, counter

So I've simplified my code down to the basics to try and get this to work. The mainpage, which you press 'play' on takes you to the page 'MathsQ1', this is the first question. The page has a question and four button, one of them being the right button. I've been able to make two different commands for the right and wrong buttons, that take you to the next question. But also I want the right function to add 1 to a counter which is called 'correct'. Once you finish the last question, it will take you the page 'MathsEnd' which will then display your score as "congrats you got (correct)/2" and I would really appreciate it if someone told me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

The code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

#INITIALIZING
class MegaQuiz(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "THE MEGA POP QUIZ")
        self.geometry("930x2000")
        self.highlightbackground="#FF846B"

        self.correct = 0

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (MainPage, MathsQ1, MathsQ2, MathsEnd):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("MainPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

class MainPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.configure(background="#FFC2B5")


        #Play BUTTON
        tk.Button(self, text="PLAY", width=10, 
                        command = lambda: controller.show_frame("MathsQ1")) .grid(column=1, row=11, columnspan=8, pady=20, sticky="nesw")

class MathsQ1(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.configure(background="#FFC2B5")

        tk.Label(self, text="Maths Quiz") .grid(column=2, row=0)

        tk.Label(self, text="Question 1") .grid(column=4, row=1, columnspan=5, sticky="nesw")

        tk.Button(self, text="wrong",
                  command=self.wrong) .grid(column=4, row=3, sticky="nesw")
        tk.Button(self, text="right",
                  command=self.right) .grid(column=4, row=5, sticky="nesw")
        tk.Button(self, text="wrong",
                  command=self.wrong) .grid(column=6, row=3, sticky="nesw")
        tk.Button(self, text="wrong",
                  command=self.wrong) .grid(column=6, row=5, sticky="nesw")

    def wrong(self):
        self.controller.show_frame("MathsQ2")

    def right(self):
        self.controller.show_frame("MathsQ2")

        self.controller.correct = self.controller.correct + 1

class MathsQ2(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.configure(background="#FFC2B5")

        tk.Label(self, text="Maths Quiz") .grid(column=2, row=0)

        tk.Label(self, text="Question 2") .grid(column=4, row=1, columnspan=5, sticky="nesw")

        tk.Button(self, text="wrong",
                  command=self.wrong) .grid(column=4, row=3, sticky="nesw")
        tk.Button(self, text="right",
                  command=self.right) .grid(column=4, row=5, sticky="nesw")
        tk.Button(self, text="wrong",
                  command=self.wrong) .grid(column=6, row=3, sticky="nesw")
        tk.Button(self, text="wrong",
                  command=self.wrong) .grid(column=6, row=5, sticky="nesw")

    def wrong(self):
        self.controller.show_frame("MathsEnd")

    def right(self):
        self.controller.show_frame("MathsEnd")

        self.controller.correct = self.controller.correct + 1

class MathsEnd(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.configure(background="#FFC2B5")

        tk.Label(self, text=("congrats you got " + str(self.controller.correct) + "/2")) .grid(column=1, row=1)

        tk.Button(self, text="Back To Home",
                            command = lambda: controller.show_frame("MainPage")) .grid(column=6, row=10, sticky="nesw", pady=10)


#RUNNING PROGRAM
app = MegaQuiz()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Tkinter but it looks like when you're initializing `frame`, you're passing the `MegaQuiz` instance as a parameter and the class you're initializing is just creating a copy of it. So `self.controller.correct` is not really referring to the `correct` of the original `Megaquiz` instance but the `correct` of the local copy of the `MegaQuiz` instance

Comment: @prithajnath: _"it looks like when you're initializing frame, you're passing the MegaQuiz instance as a parameter and the class you're initializing is just creating a copy of it. "_ - no, no copy is being made. A reference is being saved, but the object isn't being copied. The rest of your statement is false as well.

Comment: @BryanOakley Ah, you're right. Just when I thought I knew Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialise MathsEnd when you initialise the app, so the label that shows the score uses the value of controller.correct at the start of the program, which is 0.
You need to create a method in your MathsEnd class which updates the label:

```
class MathsEnd(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.configure(background="#FFC2B5")

        # create label, pack seperately so it can be configured later
        self.score = tk.Label(self)
        self.score.grid(column=1, row=1)
        # initalise using method
        self.update_label()

        tk.Button(self, text="Back To Home",
                        command = lambda: controller.show_frame("MainPage")) 
        .grid(column=6, row=10, sticky="nesw", pady=10)

    # new method to update label contents
    def update_label(self):
        self.score.config(text='Congrats you got %s/2' % self.controller.correct)
```

(I had to make some changes to how you create the label as well).

You then need to call this method to update the score whenever it is changed.

```
def right(self):
    self.controller.correct += 1
    # update score label
    self.controller.frames['MathsEnd'].update_label()

    self.controller.show_frame('MathsQ2')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understand what your saying but changing MathsEnd to what you have sent me still gives a "0" as the score.  Am I incrementing the variable incorrectly?

Comment: The incrementing is fine, are you calling the method whenever you update the score/show the MathsEnd window?

Comment: YES IT WORKS THANKYOU AAAAAAAAAAH

Comment: No problem. Please consider accepting this answer by clicking the green tick, thanks!